# Inserting a value into a field unless that field have a value of 'X' then inserting another value instead

Tags: sql

so have a  store procedure that I am trying to write (see below) what I want to do is for the 3rd field in the insert into statement (OrgSQENNo) I want it to insert the value of OrgSQENNo unless that value is 0 then I want it to insert the SQEN value instead. I think I need to use the exists or is null cause but no sure the best way to go about this.

```
(
@SEQN INT ,
@UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NEW_SEQN INT
    EXEC sp_asi_GetCounter2 'GT_INVESTMENT', @NEW_SEQN OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO [GT_INVESTMENT] 
    ([ID],[SEQN],[OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, InvestAmnt, InvestmentDate)


    SELECT [ID], @NEW_SEQN, [OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, (InvestAmnt+TotalInterest), MatDate
    FROM [GT_INVESTMENT]
    WHERE SEQN = @SEQN

END
```

Thanks in advance for everyone's help

Comment: You can just use `IF ELSE` for that. [Google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=if%20else%20sql)

Comment: You want to use `SQEN` if `OrgSQENNo` is 0 as well as null?

Comment: what would be the syntax for that in my statement

Comment: @Jonathan: that would be tricky indeed.

Comment: Alvin just 0 as it will never have a null value.

Comment: @TaunBrown: what exactly do you want to do in case of null?

Comment: What do you mean by, "I think I need to use the exists or is null cause but no sure the best way to go about this."

Comment: @AlvinThompson there should be no case where should be a null as a value in that field as it is a pure numeric field and the application that writes to the DB will always enter a 0 in that field if the user does not enter a value.

Comment: @AlvinThompson what I meant by that is just what I thought I needed to use to make it work I am still some what new to sql coding and learning as I go.

Comment: @TaunBrown: what DB is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query for the insert statement

```
    INSERT INTO [GT_INVESTMENT] 
    ([ID],[SEQN],[OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, InvestAmnt, InvestmentDate)


    SELECT [ID],@NEW_SEQN , CASE [OrgSQENNo] WHEN 0 THEN @SEQN ELSE [OrgSQENNo] END , OrgPaymentDate, (InvestAmnt+TotalInterest), MatDate
    FROM [GT_INVESTMENT]
    WHERE SEQN = @SEQN
```

Comment: He didn't say `@NEW_SEQN`.

Comment: That **may** work, but the `CASE` syntax can vary depending on SQL dialect, which he didn't specify.

Comment: By looking at the query syntax and the comments seems SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two statements:

```
INSERT INTO [GT_INVESTMENT] ([ID],[SEQN],[OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, InvestAmnt, InvestmentDate)
SELECT [ID], @NEW_SEQN, [OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, (InvestAmnt+TotalInterest), MatDate
FROM [GT_INVESTMENT]
WHERE SEQN = @SEQN AND [OrgSQENNo] != 0;

INSERT INTO [GT_INVESTMENT] ([ID],[SEQN],[OrgSQENNo], OrgPaymentDate, InvestAmnt, InvestmentDate)
SELECT [ID], @NEW_SEQN, SEQN, OrgPaymentDate, (InvestAmnt+TotalInterest), MatDate
FROM [GT_INVESTMENT]
WHERE SEQN = @SEQN AND [OrgSQENNo] = 0
```

Comment: Alvin I tried the code above first and it worked. but I believe this would have worked as well my sql knowledge is not high enough yet to know if there is a reason to use 1 code over the other but either way THANK YOU very much for your time and help.

Comment: @TaunBrown: No problem. The other answer is better if it works on your DB.